# QGIS export rotated GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, geojson, export, rotate

In QGIS one can rotate a layer on the fly using the Rotation button at bottom of pane. But I cant work out how to export the layer with the rotation applied. When exported the object is always exported in unrotated state and there is no option I can find to keep the rotation applied.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The task itself is bizarre.What does 120 degrees north look like? You can trivially rotate the axes of any JSON object, but the result of rotating a GeoJSON is not a GeoJSON.

Comment: Yeah, you should tell us what you want to achieve. If it just the visualization (a map canvas rotated 120 degrees) than this is something completely different then data itself rotated. Or do we speak about reprojecting data? Sorry, you should add more details to make clear what you want to do, what you need the rotation for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Geopandas was used to rotate the dataset

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.rotate.html